# Transferring secrets from build stage into final stage environment

Tags: docker

I use a web application provided by way of a 3rd party docker image.  This image requires secrets like DB credentials, API keys, etc that are themselves stored in Vault.

I'm trying to come up with a way of injecting the secrets into the web application's environment.

With what little I know, I think a good approach would be to incorporate a multi stage build where the builder would create and/or execute some code that would query Vault for the secrets, store them in the build stage environment where they would somehow be accessible by the final stage.

I've mocked up something pretty rudimentary based on my understanding of what might work:

```
FROM alpine AS build
ARG SECRET_1
ENV ENV_SECRET_1=$SECRET_1
RUN export ENV_SECRET_1=1

FROM alpine
ENV SECRET_1=$ENV_SECRET_1
CMD sleep infinity
```

```yaml
services:
  main:
    image: my_var_test
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        SECRET_1: ${SECRET_1}  
    environment:
      SECRET_1: ${SECRET_1}
```

But when I try to build this, a couple of things are going on.  1.  I get an error saying that the variable isn't set.  2.  The container's value for `SECRET_1` is blank:

```bash
% docker compose -f "docker-compose.yml" up -d --build 

WARN[0000] The "SECRET_1" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "SECRET_1" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
[+] Building 0.1s (5/5) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 69B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 1/1] FROM docker.io/library/alpine                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:37477bf6ebbab8ca3b37f552c08afff1e082928bde1346216020ccdaa73f33a7                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/my_var_test                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
[+] Running 2/2

% docker exec -it sidecartest-main-1 env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=f9e0cfd815e0
TERM=xterm
SECRET_1=
HOME=/root
```

What am I missing here, and perhaps any other patterns that are better common practise?

Comment: secrets should probably not be stored in the image, and should be injected at the runtime. For one thing, you would need to recompile you entire application if you need to change the secret...

Comment: Also, anything that's in the image can be fairly easily extracted afterwards, which defeats a many of the benefits of Vault.  Can your application use a Vault client to get its own secrets at startup time?

Comment: @DavidMaze The application doesn't have a built-in Vault client.  I'd need to add code to the container in order to do that.  I feel reluctant to add anything to a  3rd party container because my impression is that keeping it factory will prevent problems down the road with any changes the maintainer wants to make.  But,  maybe this is not really as big a problem as I'm making it out to be.  Food for thought indeed.

Comment: @Aron to be clear, I'm actually trying to avoid storing secrets in the image.  I'm also trying to avoid storing them in a file that is passed around, and any other insecure practise that I can think of.  The mock up in the OP sticks in `RUN export ENV_SECRET_1=1` just as a placeholder to make the MRE valid, but I was envisioning the real value of `ENV_SECRET_1` to be passed in from the vault query ie: `RUN export ENV_SECRET_1=$(kv get -field=value secret/creds)` which I think addresses the security aspect?

Comment: `RUN export ...` does nothing; the environment will be reset at the end of each shell command.  If you did manage to persist environment variables (as `ENV` does, for fixed strings) then they would be visible in clear text in `docker inspect` output.

Comment: @Jason Even IF it worked, that doesn't address the security aspect. You would still be able to extract the secret simply by running `docker exec container echo $SECRET`. You should be injecting the secret AT RUNTIME.

Comment: @Jason you can either inject the secret as an enviroment variable using `-e FOO=BAR` in the docker arguments, or by mounting the secret stored in a file.